# Run mysql query and export values as 2d JSON array

Tags: mysql

I want to run `select id, name FROM testt`

I want the results to look like:

```
[ [1, "Bob"], [2, "Jones"]]
```

How can I do that? Mysql's only options I have found want to output rows of objects with field names in every one. This is a waste of space...

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_ARRAY(id, name))
FROM testt;
```